How many solutions does the system of equations have for a figure-eight curve?
Our mathematical analysis assignment assigned the following contemplative question, which I think is quite fun:
Problem. Given function $F(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is a continuously differentiable function. (You can assume it has sufficiently nice properties.) Suppose that the graph of $F(x,y)=0$ forms a figure-eight curve, how many solutions does the system of equations $$\left\{\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)=0\\\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)=0\end{aligned}\right.$$ have at least?
My Approach. First of all, what is a "figure-eight" curve? I believe any curve that resembles the shape of an eight can be considered. For example, a double torus or two circles joined together. Next, we consider the two "O" shaped regions of this figure-eight. In fact, due to the equations, within these "O" shaped regions, $F$ is either always positive or always negative. Without loss of generality, let's assume $F$ is always positive within these "O" shaped regions. If we consider the closure, there must be a maximum value of $F(x_0, y_0)$ within this compact set, which is definitely not attained on the boundary. It's evident that the equation system is satisfied at the point $(x_0, y_0)$. Therefore, there are at least two solutions within the two "O" shaped regions. The instructor mentioned there are at least three solutions, so I think it's possible that the equation system is also satisfied at the intersection points of the two "O" shaped regions, but I'm not sure how to prove it. If at this intersection point the two tangent lines are not the same, for example, in the case of a double torus, then let the direction vectors of the two tangent lines be $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then the Jacobian matrix $$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)$$is orthogonal to them, hence zero. But what if the curve is two circles joining together? Then the two tangents are the same. Maybe there is a counterexample? Another question I have is how to construct a specific $F$ that satisfies these conditions? Thank you!
